# Images not refreshed every time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a question: I have this photo uploader which works fine. I am showing the user their new profile pic after the upload is done. It actually works and the first time a pic gets uploaded, it shows just fine. However when it's done the second time and consecutive times, it keeps showing the very first uploaded pic. I know pic no. 2 is uploaded because when I refresh the page it's there. I have a random string added to the behind of the pic to make sure the browser is forced to load the freshest copy, but somehow it only likes it the first time, after that no more. Is there anything that I overlooked here? It's wrecking my head. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks a million!

This is what I do and which works only the first time somebody uploads a pic:

```js
$("#op").fadeOut(3000, function() { 
 $(this).attr("src", "https://static.domain.com/users/"+username+"/profilepic.jpg?ref="+nr);
  $(this).load(function () {
  $(this).fadeIn(4000); 
  });
});
```

NR being the string added to force the browser to load the pic afresh (just a timestamp). Things I dreamt up myself: using an ajax call in the time that the pic has faded out to retrieve the new pic from the server, but that was giving me only hate; setTimeOut of like 5 seconds to give it time, but that didn't seem to love me either and finally a 4 second long fadeIn as seen in the snippet, but that seems to go nowhere as well. I know how it works, I just would like to know if there is anything that I may have overlooked? Any hints or tips are greatly appreciated! NB: due to time differences I may not be able to respond immediately, I am sorry about that. Thanks again in advance!

Comment: Does **nr** change on every request? https://medium.com/@codebyamir/a-web-developers-guide-to-browser-caching-cc41f3b73e7c

Comment: I don’t think nr matters. Does the variable username change?

Comment: @user2182349 Yes - nr changes on every request - it's just a string that holds the number of seconds we have at the time, like so: $nr = (strtotime("now") . "");

Comment: @andre - no, it's happening when the same user uploads a pic then changes his mind and uploads another one after that (they can only upload 1 per time). The second time I will still show the same pic as the first time.

Comment: If **nr** is set on the server side, it won’t change unless the page is reloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the same user uploads two pictures one after the other, the username stays the same, and so the uploaded file. If the username is not changing when uploading the second picture, you might want to consider generating different names for the pictures.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't considered that; let me try that and get back at you.

Comment: Ok Attila's suggestion fixed the problem. What I do now is just use the nr variable as file name and as soon as they click on the main button to create their profile, I have it renamed to profilepic again. Thank you all guys for your ideas and suggestions, greatly appreciate your input! Edit: unfortunately I can't give points yet as I don't have enough credit to do so, but you earned a +1, Attila!

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think nr matters. Does the variable username change? From the code your showing the pic is coming from a file folder with the user name and in that folder is a image with the name profilepic.img.